# Pygame window is not changing color for some reason

Tags: python, pygame

My pygame window is not changing color for some reason and i dont know why it is not changing color here is the code if you know please let me know....

I had to change the indentation

```
    import pygame

   pygame.init()
         screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

      running = True
    while running:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        
        running = False
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))




        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Do you want the color to be white? What is the color now? What do you want the color to be? Currently the color is white.

Comment: it is just a black screen

Comment: i want it to be white

Comment: What version of python are you running your script in? python3.8 makes it black. You can use 3.7 and 3.9 (which I use)

Comment: Please correct the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). It is almost impossible to spot the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to fill and update the display in the application loop instead of in the event loop. Care about the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

```py
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the colour. To do this you must have the correct `syntax` and commands. Your current code is...

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

First, make sure all `syntax` and `indentation` is correct.
Next, I'd try using  `pygame.display.update()` as it updates it just as well without flipping it.

Here is the final code. I have tested it successfully.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
```

There you go, I hope this has helped. If so, approve so others can find this helpful too.